# Transparent Image appears black on a Cached Bitmap

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I have imported the android's example project in the following link.
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

When i ran this app, I got a clean grid of images.

When i used a transparent image instead of the given ones, the transparent areas are filled with
black color.

See the image. [image: transparent areas around the instagram image became black.]

I couldn't remove this black color no matter whatever i change. I tried changing the grid view's background also. It didn't help.

To reproduce the problem, load the project given in the above link and change the first six items in imgUrls in Images.java with https://lh3.ggpht.com/vFpQP39LB60dli3n-rJnVvTM07dsvIzxrCL5xMiy1V4GV4unC1ifXkUExQ4N-DBCKwI=w124

Eg:
   public final static String[] imageUrls = new String[] {
        "https://lh3.ggpht.com/vFpQP39LB60dli3n-rJnVvTM07dsvIzxrCL5xMiy1V4GV4unC1ifXkUExQ4N-DBCKwI=w124",

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are 3 possibilities

1. Background Color of your layout is black that's why transparent area filled by black..
2. if you change the background color of layout then area color will be changed...
3. be sure your transparent file must be .png file
4. Check Also that the ImageCache uses PNG compression. The default is JPG.

Comment: Thanks man! Your third point was the problem in my case.
In the android code, while caching the image they compressed in the JPEG format. I changed it to PNG and worked fine. 

I don't see why the android code has JPEG compression when they ask everybody to use PNG. 

We can change the compress format in ImageCache file and get it working.